# Tracing may slow the web site?

Tags: asp.net

I have ASP.NET web site in production and I enabled tracing in web.config file as debugging purpose in case there is any error.  Is it possible that tracing may slow down the web site?

The web site response (ex. in buttton event) is extremely slow. And, I am wondering if this has anything to do with the tracing.

Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't be really. Where are you logging the trace to - something slow to write to? I think it's to memory by default, which shouldn't be a problem unless you're tracing out huge volumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to find out if tracing is the problem is to disable it for a time, and see if the website speeds up.